# ¿Qué palabra se puede usar en español para la palabra del inglés "bully"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, psicología

¿Cómo se podría traducir "bully" al español sin que tenga una connotación diferente?

El traductor de Google lo traduce como "matón", pero los chicos que hacen *bullying* en las escuelas pueden acosar, pegar, etc. pero en prácticamente todos los casos no matan a nadie y la palabra parece exagerada.

Comment: ¿En qué contexto lo has visto usado en inglés? Explica el término inglés para que podamos encontrar más fácilmente el equivalente español. Nótese, por cierto, que [_matón_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OcPZUHN) lo define el DLE como _Persona jactanciosa y pendenciera que procura intimidar a los demás_ (además de otro par de acepciones muy curiosas, recomendable leerlo :P). El uso que hacemos de tal palabra yo lo veo más suave y para mí no tiene siempre la connotación de que mata a alguien: hablamos de matones de barrio como el _quinqui_ del que mejor estar lejos, pero no porque vaya asesinando.

Comment: Cuando yo estaba en el colegio (hace 20 años), a esos niños se los llamaba «matón», efectivamente.

Comment: En el contexto de personas que se juntan para hacer bullying público a otras por internet en redes sociales (como Twitter principalmente) y la persona que lo recibe se termina suicidando. Porque hubo varios casos entre usuarios de que hablan en inglés pero no encuentro una palabra en español para describir ese comportamiento de patota virtual que tienen determinados grupos.

Comment: Aunque suene raro, "matón" se usa para eso, y no tiene que ver con matar. También se usa "abusón", si bien es verdad que no son demasiado usuales, pues se suelen describir con más adjetivos (el líder, el chulito, el bruto, etc.) o incluso con insultos. Para *bullying*, en cambio, sí se usa "acoso".

Answer (score 8):

Cuando yo era pequeño, lo normal era llamarlos "**abusones**":

> [**abusón, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0EZjyFf)
>
> 1. adj. Que abusa. U. t. c. s.
>
> [abusar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0EUOgTV)
>
> 1. intr. Hacer uso excesivo, injusto o indebido de algo o de alguien.
> 2. intr. Hacer objeto de trato deshonesto a una persona de menor experiencia, fuerza o poder.

Y parece que se sigue usando este término, porque nada más ponerlo en Google me ha salido un [artículo sobre *bullying*](http://m.hacerfamilia.com/ninos/noticia-puede-defenderse-nino-abuson-20150623152031.html).

EDIT: Pensaba que buscabas una traducción coloquial para *bully*, pero veo que en un comentario has puesto lo siguiente:

> En el contexto de personas que se juntan para hacer *bullying* público a otras por internet en redes sociales (como Twitter principalmente) y la persona que lo recibe se termina suicidando.

En tal caso probablemente sería más adecuado hablar de uno de los [tipos de "**acoso**"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0ZszPxA); concretamente:

> **acoso psicológico**
>
> 1. m. Práctica ejercida en las relaciones personales, consistente en dispensar un trato vejatorio y descalificador a una persona con el fin de desestabilizarla psíquicamente.

Las personas que ejercen acoso sobre otras se denominan "**acosadoras**":

> [**acosador, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0ZmmepX)
>
> 1. adj. Que acosa. U. t. c. s.

Comment: Cuando yo era pequeño, también los llamábamos "abusones".

Answer (score 4):

En Colombia estamos usando la palabra "matoneo" para referirse al acoso sistemático y continuo de una persona (o personas) hacia otra sea física o verbalmente.

Comment: Así es y suena terrible.

Answer (score 2):

En Argentina (personalmente la he  oído en distintas provincias, como Mendoza,  Tucumán) hay un verbo que encaja coloquialmente muy bien con las actitudes de abuso, amedrentamiento del "bullying" (individual, —porque sino cabría `patotear`), que es

> **prepotear**

Es una forma derivada del adjetivo

> prepotente [1](https://dle.rae.es/prepotente?m=form)

Al que la RAE define como que `abusa de su poder, o hace alarde de él`

No está totalmente extendida pero la incluyo como un aporte interesante porque es una forma coloquial muy apropiada para describir la agresividad y el exceso en el trato con intenciones humillatorias o amedrentantes para terceros.

Aquí van algunos usos en la literatura:

> Krogh [2](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=BtxSEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT263&dq=%22prepoteando%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiV4Zjawoz3AhXTnGoFHT9sBOgQuwV6BAgGEAc#v=onepage&q=%22prepoteando%22&f=false)
>
> "Ema era paciente hasta que escuchaba a alguien insultando o ***prepoteando*** a su padre, entonces no era muy capaz de controlar sus actos y su fuerza. Quizás por eso, sus hermanos cuando lo veían muy sobresaltado, preferían llamarse al (...)"

> Utopías cotidianas [3](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=WvOzjVJw1BUC&pg=PA153&dq=%22prepoteando%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiV4Zjawoz3AhXTnGoFHT9sBOgQ6AF6BAgFEAI) 
> "Éramos fuertes aún para torcer el brazo de los dinosaurios y así los compañeros fueron velados en el local del Partido. Primero fue la montada ***prepoteando*** a la imperfecta fila, multiforme en banderas (...)

Answer (score 0):

Otras opciones:

- **amedrentador**
- **bravucón**
- **intimidatorio**
- **pendenciero**

Todas abundan en el sentido de que alguien más fuerte trata de obligar a alguien a hacer algo que no quiere voluntariamente, bien con la fuerza o bien por otros medios, como el miedo.